# mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card

Tags: pi-3, wifi, bluetooth

I have a raspberry pi 3 with Jessie lite (10-APR-2017) that worked perfectly until yesterday. Now WIFI & Bluetooth don't work anymore - LAN is OK.
`dmesg` shows `mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card`
I re-imaged the SD-card with the newest Jessie Lite (05-JUL-2017)
`dmesg` shows `mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card`
`hcitool scan` shows `Device is not available: No such device`

Don't know what the problem is...

Continued on [raspberrypi.org forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=189983&p=1196317#p1196317) (no solution until now)

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @Nikhil No, WLAN and Bluetooth are dead. It's a fast RPi 2 now :-) - I bought a new  one and put it in a case to avoid ESP damage. No issues until now.